# Color Row based on "Declined" rule

Tags: excel-2010, conditional-formatting

Currently have this and other rules working properly:

> =INDIRECT("G"&ROW())="N:Declined:XXRN"
>
> =INDIRECT("G"&ROW())="N:Declined:XXCC"
>
> =INDIRECT("G"&ROW())="N:Declined:XBNC"

But, I'd like to do a wildcard so not matter what the declined code is, the row is formatted as I have configured.  But I can't get a wildcard working properly.

Tried:

> =INDIRECT("G"&ROW())="N:Declined:*"
>
> =INDIRECT("G"&ROW())="N:Declined:?"
>
> =INDIRECT("G"&ROW())="N:Declined:"&"*"

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Doh!  Next page search results helped.

> =SEARCH("N:Declined:",INDIRECT("G"&ROW()))